# Listing contents of subfolders in a Plone folder view

Tags: plone

On a Plone site with the structure

```
root
   +-topic1
   |    +-page1
   |    +-page2
   |
   +-topic2
        +-page3
        +-page4
```

I want to have a view for folder `root` that lists the contents of the subfolders, like:

```
[http://host/plone/root/]

TOPIC1

- page1
- page2

TOPIC2

- page3
- page4
```

with "TOPIC1" and "TOPIC2" as headings and "page1" etc. linking to the actual pages.

Simply using a collection aggregating the pages in the topic1 and topic2 folders is not enough since it doesn't generate the subheadings.

I have searched the Plone products repository as well as the web for an extension providing a view like this, with no success. There are sources saying this can be done with custom Display Views, but since I am new to Plone, I hesitate to dig into hacking these.

Is there a Plone product/extension that can provide such a view on subfolder contents?
Or is there even a built-in solution that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Basically, what you want to do is extend the `folder_summary_view` template to include a content list for folder and collection items.

1. **Create a copy.** In the ZMI, go to `portal_skins/plone_content/folder_summary_view` and hit *Customize*. Go to the copy at `portal_skins/custom/folder_summary_view` and rename it to (for example) `list_contents`.
2. **Activate it as folder view.** Go to `portal_types/Folder` and manually add `list_contents` to the list in *Available view methods*.
3. **Make sure the view only shows folders and collections.** Wrap the code that generates the entry details in `<tal:general_check condition="python: item_type in ('Folder', 'Topic')"> GENERATE ENTRY </tal:general_check>`
4. **Add the code for listing the item contents.** You can steal it from `portal_skins/plone_content/folder_listing` since this already does what is needed. Copy the `<metal:listingmacro> ... <metal:listingmacro>` part, but replace the `folderContents` definition in `<tal:foldercontents>` with this line to retrieve the contents:

```
folderContents folderContents|nothing;
folderContents python:item_object.queryCatalog(**contentFilter) or
item_object.getFolderContents(contentFilter, batch=True, b_size=limit_display or 100);
```

(all in one line)

Note: `item_object` is the name given to the item in the outer listing.

If you activate `list_contents` as a folder view now, it works exactly as demanded in the question.

**Warning:** This is a copy-paste-hack by a Plone novice that works for me™. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this just via the Plone-UI:

Install Products.ContentWellPortlets and assign two collection-portlets below the content to your portal's default-view-item (f.e. 'front-page' as by default).

Comment: Thanks, but I've abandoned Plone since. Too much hassle for too simple tasks. :-/

Comment: You're welcome. Just for curiosity: what did you choose instead?

Comment: A homebrew for a quick fix (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycms), and looking at Django. :-)

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising, I'll have a closer look at this one of these winterdays. Have you heard of 'Kotti'? They have the same motivations. Didn't try it yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Collection here, with the two paths configured as criteria.
And if you want to, you could use this collection as default view for "root". Have a look at the default "news" and "events" folders and collections, located in it.

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/using-collections/adding-collections

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I've tried it, a Collection simply aggregates the pages - it does neither produce subheadings nor sort the pages by folder. This is a requirement. I have clarified the question above.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Collections (internally called ATTopic) anyway. It is then possible to write a custom view to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/a-simple-at-product/view-template

Comment: +1 on writing a browser view for this, better to use collections as the basis for it.  Don't think of this as a structural problem, but a behavioral problem -- you likely just want a custom view regardless of whether you add it for folders or use if for a collection.